# If else condition in multiple from in LINQ in C#

Tags: c#, linq

I have linq query where I need to set condition if `p.conditionVariable > 0` I would apply the following condition.

```
from prob in table2.where(p => p.Id == p.ConditionVariable && !p.IsBlocked && p.IsActive)
```

if p.conditionVariable == 0 the following remains the same.

```
(from _obj1 in table1.Where(p => p.IsActive == true))
                           from prob in table2.Where(p => p.Id == _obj1.Id && !p.IsBlocked && p.IsActive && p.ConditionVariable == 0)
                           select new Class1
                           {
                               Title = prob.Title,
                               Status = prob.IsPending,
                               Id = obj1.id 
                           }
```

Comment: I have no idea what you are asking, please clarify the question. What if p.ConditionVariable != 0?

Comment: If p.ConditionVariable != 0, I need to get the record from table2 with id == ConditionVariable. I'll explain in detail. I have a scenario where table2 has a column called ConditionVariable and id. ConditionVariable will not have any value by default. If it has any value then I need to search the id which is equal to conditionvariable in table2. Hope you got my point

Comment: I have no idea what you are asking either but it sounds like the answer involves a [ternary operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty67wk28.aspx)

Comment: @adricadar from table2

Comment: @HafizH can you give a feedback of solutions below?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want to make a `||` between conditions and `table2` will be queried based on `p.CondtionVariable`.

```
(from _obj1 in table1.Where(p => p.IsActive == true))
   from prob in table2.Where(p => (p.Id == _obj1.Id && !p.IsBlocked && p.IsActive && p.ConditionVariable == 0)
                               || (p.ConditionVariable > 0 && p.Id == p.ConditionVariable && !p.IsBlocked && p.IsActive))
   select new Class1
   {
       Title = prob.Title,
       Status = prob.IsPending,
       Id = _obj1.id 
   }
```

If you want to use `if/else` conditions, you can use something like this

```
(from _obj1 in table1.Where(p => p.IsActive == true))
   from prob in table2.Where(p => {
            bool state = false;
            if(p.ConditionVariable > 0)  {
                state = p.Id == p.ConditionVariable && !p.IsBlocked && p.IsActive;
            } else if(p.ConditionVariable == 0) {
                state = p.Id == _obj1.Id && !p.IsBlocked && p.IsActive;
            }
            return state;   
        })
   select new Class1
   {
       Title = prob.Title,
       Status = prob.IsPending,
       Id = _obj1.id 
   }
```

Comment: if "p.Id == p.ConditionVariable" this condition is used, it will get the records where id and Condtionvariable is same. But my case is, if conditionvariable > 0. I need the record with id equals to that conditionVariable. I'm really sorry if i am making it complex

Answer (score 0):

I would put the p.ConditionVariable test at the beginning so taht it is the first thing checked (as && operations stop at the first failing condition. IF the first check fails then the || operation is checked next):

```
(from _obj1 in table1.Where(p => p.IsActive == true))
                           from prob in table2.Where(
                               (p => p.ConditionVariable == 0 && p.Id == _obj1.Id && !p.IsBlocked && p.IsActive) 
                               || (p.ConditionVariable > 0 && p.Id == p.ConditionVariable && !p.IsBlocked && p.IsActive))
                           select new Class1
                           {
                               Title = prob.Title,
                               Status = prob.IsPending,
                               Id = obj1.id 
                           }
```

A second variant would also be possible with myvariable=0 ? .... as someone commented but in this case it is not really necessary as you have the || && operators there anyway.